# How can I measure the response (processing) times of a SuT using JMS Point-to-Point messaging model through IBM MQ?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jms, performance-testing, ibm-mq

I have a remote IBM MQ instance set up with 2 queues. Behind them is a System Under Test which always picks up messages put on the INBOUND.QUEUE" does some processing and places a response message on the "OUTBOUND.QUEUE".

I wish to test the response times of this SuT. To achieve this I need to put in place this scenario:

- JMeter sends some message with ID1 to a queue named "INBOUND.QUEUE"
- The System under test takes the message from "INBOUND.QUEUE", does some processing and places the response on "OUTBOUND.QUEUE"
- JMeter checks and asserts that a response has been received for the message with ID1 on the queue named "OUTBOUND.QUEUE" within X seconds
- View response time results in Aggregate Report Listener

In JMeter I have a setup very similar to the one described in this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how), using JSR223 test elements with groovy code to interact with the IBM MQ Queues - through [JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/jms/package-summary.html?view=embed), if my understanding is correct. The difference from the article is that in order to consume messages from the outbound queue, I have another setUp Thread Group which sets up another connection for the "OUTBOUND.QUEUE" from which I consume the messages and another tearDown Thread Group which closes this connection at the end.

On a high-level my setup looks like this:
[image]
[image]

It works so far, but it blindly consumes messages and I need to ensure that I'm reading (consuming) the response continuation of each initial message so that I may calculate the response or processing time of the SuT for each complete request-response flow.
I understood that I can use [JMS Correlation ID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs25/interopjms/MsgIDPatternforJMS.html) for this purpose but I don't know how.

1. What method can I use to get this Correlation ID at message creation and consumption time?
2. Do I need some data structure to put all the Correlation IDs at the message creation time so that I can put a condition like IF msg.getStringProperty("JMS_CorreationID") is IN list of produced ids, remove it from this data structure, then get the JMS_IBM_PUTTIME property to determine the timestamp for the "first" message, then finally calculate the timestamp delta between the current time and the time for the first message ?
3. Once I would do this, how can I configure the JSR223 Sampler (Consumer) in the 2nd Thread Group via [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance so it would report not its own execution time but the delta between JMS_IBM_PUTTIME and the current time (which would represent the processing time)?
4. Finally, once this is done, how can I include into the load test report only this 2nd JSR223 Sampler (Consumer)?

Is this logic correct/too complex?
Any help or some code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you're supposed to be asking only one question in one post, I don't think anyone is willing to write a book to answer all the questions you have (and doing your job for you for free)

1. If you want to use JMS Correlation ID you need to explicitly call [Message.setJMSCorrelationID()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID(java.lang.String)) function in the producer and correspondingly read it as [Message.getJMSCorrelationID()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSCorrelationID()) in the consumer
2. Yep, you can either use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) or `props` shorthand for [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) class instance
3. You can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), add it as a child of the JSR223 Sampler and use `prev.elapsedTime = 123456`, replace `123456` with the actual delta between sent and received message with the given correlation ID
4. You can use [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function, this way the JSR223 Sampler where you call this function will neither be displayed in Listeners nor in .jtl results file.